# How to outsource HTML Tags from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am wondering how to separate JavaScript and HTML. Of course, i include JS with:

```
<script src="function.js"></script>
```

But when i add dynamically HTML-Tags to the website with JS like:

```
 $( "#content" ).append("<h2>");
```

Then there are HTML Tags inside JavaScript Code. Can i make this modular or is there any "Good Practice" to do it?

Or should i use a framework like **Bootstrap** to code larger projects and exclude those frameworks the HTML Tags?

Comment: If you want a template framework, [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) would be a good choice.

Comment: AngularJS is not just a template framework, it is a complete MVC framework with templating. Perhaps AngularJS is a little overkill if you just look for a templating framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to separate your application logic from the layout, you should use a template framework. There are a lot of frameworks out there who do the job like:

- [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)
- [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)
- [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)
- and many [more](http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/templating-engines-9134396)

What you essentially do is providing data objects to the template engine. Based on the logic you define in the template you render the page without the need to clutter the application logic and the layout.

In order to find the right template engine for your application you might want to check out: http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/ Here you can define what kind of engine you are looking for and the website shows you the most suitable library.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a hidden template object, then `.clone()` it in javascript. Or use one of many MVVM / template javascript frameworks